# Unable to parse XML after writing it Code Synthesis

Tags: c++, xml, codesynthesis

After writing a XML using my project when i try to parse it using Codesynthesis

```
simulation_results sim_results;
try{

    QString result_xml= "..\\XML\\My.xml";
    sim_results =*simulation_results_(result_xml.toStdString(), xsd::cxx::tree::flags::dont_validate);
}
catch (const xml_schema::exception& e)
{
    std::ostringstream os;
    os << e;
    std::string s = os.str ();
}
```

This parse fails,but if i try to parse this XML without changing it first everything is fine.

Bottom lines , when i first create it and then parse it fails.It is like is still open or need to be refreshed?